# KeyError: 'queryStringParameters' while testing PATCH on POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, http, postman, aws-api-gateway

I have a api set up with api gateway for PATCH method which is integrated with an lambda function.

I am trying to test my api with POSTMAN.

[image]

As you can see i am facing the above error.
I have used the same method to pull the query parameter in other methods like GET,PUT,DELETE worked like a charm.

I am using Python to script my lambda.

I figure this error is more related to API end than of the code.

Could any one help me out of this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently i had missed to click on the radio button to have a proxy integrate while integrating with my lambda function.

[image]

PATCH can work with query parameters.